# Vuejs 3.3 defineModel always returns undefined what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt 3.5.1 and Vuejs 3.3 but defineModel macro always returns undefined I don't know why?

```
 <template>
     <input v-model="count">
</template>

 <script lang="ts" setup>
   const count = defineModel('count');

   debugger //====when I stopped here I get count undefined
</script>
I added this section to nuxt.config.ts but with no success:
vite:{      
         vue: {
             script: {
                 defineModel: true,
                 propsDestructure: true                 
             }
         }
     
   }
```

Comment: defineModel requires Vue 3.3 and **explicit opt-in**.  Did you opt-in?  [scroll down to 'Adoption Strategy'](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/503) for instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem there is section in my nuxt.config.ts that conflict with vite section:

```
//=====when I disable this section it works fine
 hooks: {
       "vite:extendConfig": (config, { isClient, isServer }) => {
          if (isClient) {
             config.vue =   "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler";           
          }
       },
    },
//===this is the vite section
 vite:{      
         vue: {
             script: {
                 defineModel: true,
                 propsDestructure: true                 
             }
         }
     
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my nuxt config as you said

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    vue: {
      script: {
        defineModel: true,
        propsDestructure: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And the my component

```
<script setup>
const count = defineModel();

console.log(count?.value);

watch(
  () => count.value,
  (n) => {
    console.log(n);
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="count" />
</template>
```

Remember that as the official blog said [link](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#definemodel)

> 3.3 simplifies the usage with the new defineModel macro. The macro automatically registers a prop, and returns a ref that can be directly mutated:

It's working fine. I think Here's the **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pszns7?file=nuxt.config.ts)** link. Check out the code. It's working file and printing value properly in the console.

Comment: What is your nuxt version?

Comment: Checkout the StackBlitz link where is the full code. I used Nuxt 3.5.1